# How can I reload properties file in Spring 4 using annotations?

Tags: java, spring, properties, annotations

I have a simple application where i am using several properties-files to fetch content edited by other users (links to sites etc).

The class where i load the properties look like this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:salestipsWhitelist.properties")
public class SalestipsWhitelist {

@Autowired
Environment env;

public Environment getEnv() {
    return env;
}

public void setEnv(Environment env) {
    this.env = env;
}

@Bean
   public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
      return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
   }
}
```

Some of the properties file:

```
UPS_MPP_M_L=True
UPS_MPP_M_M=True
UPS_MPP_M_MP=True
UPS_MPP_M_S=True
```

This works fine, but if i make changes to the properties-file, i have to reload the app to visualise any changes made.

Is it possible, if i move the location to disk instead of classpath, to reload this periodically or manually? I do not want this to be done automatically on change, as i want to have control over when this is done / updated.

Answer (score 11):

This works a treat. Requires Java 7, Apache commons logging, Apache commons lang (v2.6) and Apache commons Configuration:

```
package corejava.reloadTest;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.reloading.FileChangedReloadingStrategy;

public class MyApplicationProperties {
    private static PropertiesConfiguration configuration = null;

    static {
        try {
            configuration = new PropertiesConfiguration("test.properties");
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        configuration.setReloadingStrategy(new FileChangedReloadingStrategy());
    }

    public static synchronized String getProperty(final String key) {
        return (String) configuration.getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

and test it with:

```
package corejava.reloadTest;

public class TestReloading {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(MyApplicationProperties.getProperty("key"));
        }
    }
}
```

Output when you change test.properties is something like this (original contents of test.props was key=value, later changed to key=value1 mid-program execution):

```
value
value
value
value
value
Jan 17, 2015 2:05:26 PM org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration reload
INFO: Reloading configuration. URL is file:/D:/tools/workspace   /AutoReloadConfigUsingApacheCommons/resources/test.properties
value1
value1
value1
```

You could also consider **Official Spring Framework Reference Documentation** [Refreshable beans](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#dynamic-language-refreshable-beans) , using a **DSL** like Groovy for this.

Comment: what if properties in jar file?

Comment: It should not otherwise you will have to redeploy each time you want to change a configuration value

Answer (score 7):

the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer need to be override to reload the new Properties

You need to rewrite `processProperties` method to make the `StringValueResolver` which contains the properties became to  loadable.
This is my code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper;
import org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.PlaceholderResolver;
import org.springframework.util.StringValueResolver;


public class ReloadablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer 
                                    extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

    private ReloadablePlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver reloadableValueResolver;


    public void reloadProperties() throws IOException {
        Properties props = mergeProperties();
        this.reloadableValueResolver.refreshProperties(props);
    }


    @Override
    protected void processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactoryToProcess, Properties props)
            throws BeansException {
        this.reloadableValueResolver = new ReloadablePlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver(props);
        StringValueResolver valueResolver = this.reloadableValueResolver;
        this.doProcessProperties(beanFactoryToProcess, valueResolver);
    }


    private class ReloadablePlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver 
            implements StringValueResolver {

        private final PropertyPlaceholderHelper helper;
        private final ReloadablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurerResolver resolver;

        public ReloadablePlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver(Properties props) {
            this.helper = new PropertyPlaceholderHelper(placeholderPrefix, placeholderSuffix, valueSeparator, ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders);
            this.resolver = new ReloadablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurerResolver(props);
        }

        @Override
        public String resolveStringValue(String strVal) throws BeansException {
            String value = this.helper.replacePlaceholders(strVal, this.resolver);
            return (value.equals(nullValue) ? null : value);
        }

        private void refreshProperties(Properties props){
            this.resolver.setProps(props);
        }
    }

    private class ReloadablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurerResolver 
            implements PlaceholderResolver {

        private Properties props;
        private ReloadablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurerResolver(Properties props) {
            this.props = props;
        }

        @Override
        public String resolvePlaceholder(String placeholderName) {
            return ReloadablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.this.resolvePlaceholder(placeholderName, props, SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_FALLBACK);
        }

        public void setProps(Properties props) {
            this.props = props;
        }
   }
}
```

here is the configure for `properties-config.xml` .all of those properties can be reload in runtime as a prototype bean.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="com.cn21.mail189.analysis.commons.expand.ReloadablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <!-- database config -->
            <value>classpath:spring/dbconfig.properties</value>
            <!-- app config -->
            <value>classpath:spring/app.properties</value>
            <!-- some other config -->
            <value>classpath:xxxx.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>`
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It helps if you can add code to show the answer.

Comment: in `processProperties` we pass `StringValueResolver` into `doProcessProperties` which would stored into beanfactory. Default `PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver` in `PlaceholderConfigurerSupport` class hold the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurerResolver`  who keep the properties in final attritube when place it in `getContext` method,we need to rewrite it

Comment: How can we reflect these properties changes in a predefined bean?

Answer (score 0):

Inside applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="beanId" class="org.apache.commons.configuration.reloading.FileChangedReloadingStrategy">
    <property name="refreshDelay" value="30000" /> <!-- 30 seconds -->
</bean>
<bean id="reloadableProperties" class="org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration">
    <constructor-arg value="file:/web/${weblogic.Domain}/${weblogic.Name}/${app.Name}/reloadable_cfg/Reloadable.properties"/>
    <property name="reloadingStrategy" ref="propertiesReloadingStrategy"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: How can we reflect these properties to a predefined bean?