# Properties change with out a server restart

Tags: spring, properties

I have externalized all my application needed property files from webapps in tomcat. Now i can simply change a property file value without a need of rebuilding the war file and deploy it again. However each change to property file is associated with server recyling.

Is there a way how the recycling can be avoided for a property file change. 
I am using spring to read the property files for few webapps and java property traditional way for few webapps.

Please suggest how to acheive

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I reload properties file in Spring 4 using annotations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150527/how-can-i-reload-properties-file-in-spring-4-using-annotations)

Comment: what approach you followed?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider [spring-cloud-config-server](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/) or [spring-cloud-consul](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/spring-cloud-consul.html) all of these options supports distributed properties management as well as value changes refresh without a need to recycle app servers.

And you can use `@RefreshScope` for Spring `@Beans` that want to be reinitialized when configuration changes, they also provide the following Management endpoints out of the box and many more as explained  on the project [git page](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config)

- `/refresh` for refreshing the `@RefreshScope` beans
- `/restart` for restarting the Spring context (disabled by default)

This is supported by either option (spring-cloud-config-server or spring-cloud-consul)

Comment: This works for only Git repo as location for all the property files. How about native profile, with file back-end system for the properties?

Answer (score 1):

You may also give [cfg4j](http://cfg4j.org) a try. It supports reloading configuration from local files as well as remote services (git repository, Consul, etc.).