# How to maintain, update application properties dynamically in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I would like to maintain a list of application properties like service endpoints, application variables, etc. in a Spring application. These properties should be able to updated dynamically (possibly through an web page by system administrator).

Does spring has an inbuilt feature to accomplish this requirement?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150527/how-can-i-reload-properties-file-in-spring-4-using-annotations In addition to the solutions posted one comment references the following built-in functionality: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#dynamic-language-refreshable-beans

Comment: You might want to have a look at spring-boot admin. http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.5.3/

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure spring has an implementation for updating the properties file dynamically.

You can do something like reading the properties file using `FileInputStream` into a `Properties` object. Then you will be able to update the properties. Later you can write back the properties to the same file using the `FileOutputStream`.

```
// reading the existing properties
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("propertiesFile");
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(in);
in.close();
// writing back the properties after updation
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("propertiesFile");
props.setProperty("property", "value");
props.store(out, null);
out.close();
```

Comment: we will be able to update or maybe add properties as well with this.. but we will need to restart the server so that the updates/additions take effect. isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but check if you can make use @ConfigurationProperties of Spring boot framework.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:application.properties", ignoreUnknownFields = false, prefix = "spring.datasource")
```

1. You can keep this application.properties file in you classpath
2. Change the properties in this file without redeploying the application

Java Experts - I am just trying to explore my view. Corrections are always welcome.

Edit - I read a good examples on @PropertySource [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Externalizing properties, take a look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Spring loads these properties which can be configured at runtime and accessed in your application in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Add your own implementation of a [`PropertySource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertySource.html) to your `Environment`.

***Warning:*** Properties used by `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@Value` annotations are only read once on application startup, so changing the actual property values at runtime will have no effect (until restarted).