# Specify a relative path in application properties spring file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback

I have not found any question with the same issue, but I'm sorry if the question is a duplicate.

I have this application.properties file:

```
## Logback
#logging.level.root=error
#logging.level.com.myapp.test=error
#logging.console=true
#logging.path=%AppData%/MyFolder/log
#logging.file=${logging.path}/logfile.log
```

And this is my logback.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] [%F:%L] - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${logging.file}</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] [%F:%L] - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.myapp.test" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

The problem is I don't know how to specify the relative path %AppData% in my application.properties file. I want to use %AppData% or similar because the application will run on differents servers and I want to use the path:
`C:\Users\$USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\MyFolder\log`

Is that possible?

Comment: See it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192085/how-to-maintain-update-application-properties-dynamically-in-spring

Comment: @AllanBraga that SO has nothing to do with this question - except that both are about spring properties.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531661/using-env-variable-in-spring-boots-application-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are automatically mapped into your Spring configuration. So you should be able to use them like any other configuration variable:

```
# Logback
logging.level.root=error
logging.level.com.myapp.test=error
logging.console=true
logging.path=${APPDATA}/MyFolder/log
logging.file=${logging.path}/logfile.log
```

See [Spring Boot - 24. Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)