# How to import env file variables into application.properties in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables, dotenv, application.properties

I'm running a SpringBoot application that needs environmental variables.
How can I use the values of variables declared in an `.env` file inside the `application.properties` file in spring-boot?

.env

```sh
PORT=12345
```

application.properties

```yaml
server.port=$PORT
```

Comment: check this link which shows how to dynamically update the application properties. You can get the env properties using System class. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192085/how-to-maintain-update-application-properties-dynamically-in-spring#:~:text=You%20can%20do%20something%20like,same%20file%20using%20the%20FileOutputStream%20.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work, as it worked in my system.

I am using `application.properties` file for configuration.

In **`.env`** file add `PORT` in key value pair

> PORT=12345

In **`application.properties`** file add `spring.config.import` to import the `.env` file in `application.properties`

> spring.config.import=optional:file:.env[.properties]
>
> server.port=${PORT}

To access the **PORT** value in `application.properties` use **${YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME}** for expected value in **server.port**.

Comment: I think this should be considered as the correct answer. It works even on IDE like Netbeans

Comment: what is the meaning of [.properties] after .env?

Answer (score 0):

Just add @PropertySource that points to the .env file.