# Spring Reload Property - Bean not updated

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-bean

I have a webservice that fetches property from application.properties file located in server like query[testSql] through spring

```
public class RuntimeEnvironmentPropertiesConfigurerextends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
        implements InitializingBean, RuntimeEnvironmentInterface
```

Now that query is injected in my Spring bean dao.

```
<bean id="dao" name="dao" class="com.dao.DaoImpl">
  <property name="ackJdbcTemplate"  ref="ackJdbcTemplate" />  
  <property name="testSql" value="${dao.query.tSql}" />
 </bean>
```

With  help from [How can I reload properties file in Spring 4 using annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150527/how-can-i-reload-properties-file-in-spring-4-using-annotations/42247839#42247839) link I am able to reload the property at run time.
verified by

```
@Autowired
public RuntimeEnvironmentInterface propertyLoader;

....

  Set s=propertyLoader.getProperties();
        Iterator itr=s.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
        String tempKey=String.valueOf(itr.next());
        logger.info(tempKey +"==="+propertyLoader.getProperty(tempKey));
```

but problem is my dao bean does not take updated testSql query.It runs on old one untill I restart the application.

I found a way like in separate url mapping i wrote a method which does below  job:

```
Dao.setTestSql(propertyLoader.getProperty("com.dao.query.tSql"));
```

and the person who is updating she have to hit the url after updating the property.

But this I have to do for all the bean and and injected property.That is pretty hectic  job.I miss one property and I am doomed.
Is there any other way to automatically update the injected bean?I need that my updated properties are reflected without restart .

I tried to understand wuenschenswert code given but was unable to.

Comment: Why don't you use propertyLoader in your DAO?

Comment: @Alexey Soshin Thank you for the suggestion but there is more than12 beans in the total application and there are so many properties,so I am searching for ways to reload all property without have to go to each Spring bean and setting properties.

Answer (score 2):

```
<property name="testSql" value="${dao.query.tSql}" />
```

This means that on bean initialization Spring computes the property value using a property called `dao.query.tSql`. So `setTestSql()` method will be called when the context is initialized, and that's all. When your properties are reloaded, property loader will not *push* new property value into your bean.

But, as Alexey suggests, you can *pull* the property value from your `propertyLoader` every time you execute that sql query like this:

```
final String actualQuery = propertyLoader.getProperty("com.dao.query.tSql");
executeQuery(actualQuery);
```

There is a problem: this may start look ugly when the number of properties grows. But this can be alleviated, if you create some class encapsulating these accesses; that class will provide properties via its methods. Example:

```
public class DynamicProperties {
    private final RuntimeEnvironmentInterface propertyLoader;

    public DynamicProperties(RuntimeEnvironmentInterface propertyLoader) {
        this.propertyLoader = propertyLoader;
    }

    public String tSql() {
        return propertyLoader.getProperty("dao.query.tSql");
    }

    ... other methods for other properties
}
```

Then create an instance of this class in your `Dao`:

```
private DynamicProperties dynamicProperties = new DynamicProperties(propertyLoader);
```

And then

```
executeQuery(dynamicProperties.tSql());
```

A little bonus: you can make type conversions in that same `DynamicProperties` class (for example, when your property is `int` and not `String`).

Comment: @RomanThats a pretty cool idea about the wrapper!!! I But there is more than12 beans in the total application and there are so many properties injected in those beans,so I am searching for ways to reload all property without have to go to each Spring bean and setting properties. So in future they add remove or update any bean defination there is no need to change the method.The method will reaload all the property from the file and update the property whenever it is used.