# How to resolve all placeholders which start with "something" in spring environment properties?

Tags: java, spring

I have a Java lib which is based on Spring Boot. In my case I need to resolve placeholders which start with `something.*` in my own way before this property will be resolved by some Spring Property Resolver. For example:

**application.properties**:

```
spring.datasource.url="${something.url}"
```

So this placeholder is matching my `something.*` pattern and I want to replace it with `specific` word before Spring will try to resolve it. Where can I do it so I can avoid creating system properties with `System.setProperty`?

Here is my attempts on achieving it:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper;
import org.springframework.util.StringValueResolver;

import java.util.Properties;

public class MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected void processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactoryToProcess, Properties props)
            throws BeansException {
        StringValueResolver valueResolver = new ReloadablePlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver(props);
        this.doProcessProperties(beanFactoryToProcess, valueResolver);
    }

    private class ReloadablePlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver
            implements StringValueResolver {

        private final PropertyPlaceholderHelper helper;
        private final ReloadablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurerResolver resolver;

        public ReloadablePlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver(Properties props) {
            this.helper = new MyPropertyPlaceholderHelper(placeholderPrefix, placeholderSuffix, valueSeparator, ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders);
            this.resolver = new ReloadablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurerResolver(props);
        }

        @Override
        public String resolveStringValue(String strVal) throws BeansException {
            String value = this.helper.replacePlaceholders(strVal, this.resolver);
            return (value.equals(nullValue) ? null : value);
        }
    }

    private class ReloadablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurerResolver
            implements PropertyPlaceholderHelper.PlaceholderResolver {

        private Properties props;
        private ReloadablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurerResolver(Properties props) {
            this.props = props;
        }

        @Override
        public String resolvePlaceholder(String placeholderName) {
            return MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.this.resolvePlaceholder(placeholderName, props, SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_FALLBACK);
        }
    }
}
```

Initializing bean:

```
@Bean
public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

Getting resolved property:

```
@RestController
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @GetMapping("/getEnvProeprty")
    public String getEnvironmentName() {
        return environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.url");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd be interested to know what you would like to replace 'something' with in this case, since this might give a simpler solution. You could look to create a custom bean with extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, this gives you hook points to apply your property name substitution logic and then pass back to spring to set the values see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150527/how-can-i-reload-properties-file-in-spring-4-using-annotations/39138850#39138850

Comment: I created a custom PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean like in your example but it didn't work.

Comment: It is created via `new` declaration in `AbstractEnvironment`: `private final ConfigurablePropertyResolver propertyResolver = new PropertySourcesPropertyResolver(this.propertySources);`

Comment: I suggest you post the code for your custom class and details of the error you are seeing.

Comment: I posted my code. I also debuged the stacktrace of getting property and I could not find where this `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is used.

Comment: @Praytic did you solve this use case? I'm also looking for the similar one.

Comment: No, feel free to post the answer here if you find one.

Comment: @Praytic i have solved a similar use case and posted an answer, for more details you can refer to the article that i have shared in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement and solved this use case.

In short:

Since spring tries to resolve the properties in the order from list of porperty sources, the basic idea is to add our custom property source at the top[0th index] of the PropertySources in the current `Environment`.

To do that, override the `getAppliedPropertySources()` method in `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java` class and do `addFirst` the custom property source in the current spring `Evnironment`. So that spring will try to resolve the placeholder from our custom source first, and if not found, goes through the remaining property sources.

```
@Configuration

public class CustomPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer {

private static final String[] IGNORABLE_SECRETS = new String[] {"secrets.property1", "secrets.property2"};

@Override
public PropertySources getAppliedPropertySources() throws IllegalStateException {

    // gets the applied property sources
    MutablePropertySources appliedPropertySources = (MutablePropertySources) super.getAppliedPropertySources();

    // fetches the property source of the current evnironment
    PropertySource<?> environmentPropertySource = appliedPropertySources.get("environmentProperties");

    if (Objects.nonNull(environmentPropertySource)) {
        addCustomPropertySourceToIgnoreRefresh(environmentPropertySource);
    }
    return appliedPropertySources;
}

private void addCustomPropertySourceToIgnoreRefresh(PropertySource<?> environmentPropertySource) {
    Map<String, Object> customPropertyMap = new HashMap<>();
    
    // Iterating over properties listed in IGNORABLE_SECRETS to override them
           
    for (String ignorableSecretProperty: IGNORABLE_SECRETS) {

        customPropertyMap.put(ignorableSecretProperty, "customValueForThatPorperty");
        
        // For my use case, i'm trying to fetch the secrets from the property sources that are loaded
        // during the bootstrap phase and using them as sort of cache so that spring boot doesn't 
        // need to make grpc calls to google to resolve the secrets during the consul refresh
        //  customPropertyMap.put(ignorableSecretProperty,
        //                  environmentPropertySource.getProperty(ignorableSecretProperty));

    }
    ConfigurableEnvironment configurableEnvironment =
            (ConfigurableEnvironment) environmentPropertySource.getSource();

    // post fetching the configurable environment, adding my hash map as custom map property source
    configurableEnvironment.getPropertySources()
                           .addFirst(new MapPropertySource("customPropertySource", customPropertyMap));
}

@Override
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    super.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
}
```

}

For more details you can refer to the [article](https://medium.com/@shashikanth.gajjelli/overriding-placeholder-properties-during-spring-boot-consul-refresh-c9e2ec40b470) that I have published in medium.