# Spring Boot field watcher (observer) or something similar

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How to run a method in Spring Boot when the value of concrete database field changed or it reached a certain level (programmatically)? The user wants to choose which field the method will respond to. Is there any common solution or best practice in Spring Boot?

Comment: Seems like you are looking for some opinione based answer. Do add some of your approches you thought of.

Comment: before I begin to invent my own solution, I would like to know if there is already a prepared solution by Spring or Hibernate or at least to indicate how to get started

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking is reload a bean when the properties which are loading from db is changed. you can use something similar here in this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150527/how-can-i-reload-properties-file-in-spring-4-using-annotations) with ApplicationContextAware in prototype scope.